# Error running prediction on mxnet: Check failed: i >= 0 && i < ndim(): index = 0 must be in range [0, -1)

Tags: python, mxnet

I created a trained model and I'm now trying to run prediction. I loaded my model and my prediction data.
My prediction file is a CSV with 3 columns. Here is my code

```
mod = mx.module.Module.load("mx-mod", 0)
data_iter = mx.io.CSVIter(data_csv=os.path.join(ML_DIR_LOCAL, "predict.csv"),
                          batch_size=1,
                          data_shape=(3, ))
mod.bind(data_shapes=data_iter.provide_data)
mod.predict(data_iter)
```

The bind method fails with this error:
`Check failed: i >= 0 && i < ndim(): index = 0 must be in range [0, -1)`
which I don't understand